# android:showAsAction="always" and ListActivity crash with: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-bluetooth, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to adapt an example from the excellent book [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033011.do).

Here is their [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/microbuilder/IntroToBLE/tree/master/TestApplicationAccelerator/src/com/example/testapplicationaccelerator) and here is their [res/menu/main.xml](https://github.com/microbuilder/IntroToBLE/tree/master/TestApplicationAccelerator/res/menu):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_scan" 
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="Scan"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_stop" 
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="Stop"></item>
```

However in my own app I would like to use `ListActivity` as the base clase for main `MainActivity.java` (because I would like to display found Bluetooth devices in that main list).

This results in my app crashing with the obscure error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{de.afarber.mynotification/de.afarber.mynotification.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I suppose it happens because I want the "Scan" and "Stop" buttons to be displayed in the `ActionBar`, but I am not using `ActionBarActivity` as the base class.

Is there please a way to workaround it and still use a `ListActvivity`?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, along with the source to the method(s) referenced in that stack trace, pointing out where you are crashing. "I am not using ActionBarActivity as the base class" -- since your menu resource XML is not set up for AppCompat, that is perfectly fine. You are using the native action bar on API Level 11+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was trying to use `mBlewWrapper` before creating it :-)

```
if (mBleWrapper.checkBleHardwareAvailable() == false) {
    Toast.makeText(this, 
                   R.string.no_ble_hardware, 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}       

mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null() {
    @Override
    public void uiDeviceFound(final BluetoothDevice device, 
                              final int rssi, 
                              final byte[] record) {
        Log.d("uiDeviceFound", device.getName()+", "+
              rssi+", "+record.toString());
    }
});
```

Thanks and +1 to CommonWare for his comment.